# Guice custom binding annotation fails, but @Named works?

Tags: java, guice

I'd thought that a custom binding annotation @Foo was equivalent in functionality to @Named("foo"). Is this not true?

I've got, in separate GuiceModules, two things providing the same item type:

```
In GuiceModuleFoo
@Foo
@Provides
public String provideFoo() { return "foo"; }

In GuiceModuleBar
@Bar
@Provides
public String provideBar() { return "bar"; }

class MyOtherThing extends Thing {
    @Inject
    public MyOtherThing(@Foo String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

Further, in case it matters, I'm using Modules.override so that GuiceModuleBar overrides GuiceModuleFoo (for an unrelated provide).

MyOtherThing is not getting injected with the @Foo provided value though. It's getting the value from the @Bar provider. It actually seems somewhat random what provides it when I added a 3rd provider @Baz.

However, when converting everything to use @Named (e.g. @Named("foo")), it works exactly as desired!

So...am I misunderstanding how binding annotations work? The custom annotations looked like this:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not using the module overrides to ensure that this is not affecting things?

Comment: No, because without overrides the Guice lifecycle won't start at all due to a provider conflict. My biggest wonder is if this is a bug or if I just don't understand custom binding annotations.

Comment: Have you tried binding the annotation in a `bind()` statement? The documentation for [BindingAnnotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) doesn't show you being able to stick it on a `@Provides` method in a module.

Comment: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods shows using a custom binding annotation and @Provides.

Comment: Your binding annotation looks like it should, and the code that you have that provides and consumes it looks like it should. Can you add details about the way you're using Modules.override, and can you confirm that you're not trying to simultaneously use `extends` and `Modules.override`?

Comment: Jeff, not sure what you mean by "extends". I'm doing Modules.override(GuiceModuleFoo).with(GuiceModuleB). Then that resulting module is actually overridden by a 3rd module.